# FindRoot not recognising replaced symbol in nested function

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, iteration

I have the following example FindRoot function as part of a Nest function.

```
Clear[del]
del[x_] := Module[{y, dP, res, OP},
res := {y} /. FindRoot[y^2 + 2 y - x, {y, 0}];
OP := res[[1]];
dP := OP + 1;
Nest[(# + dP/#)/2 &, 1.5, 2]
]
del[name] /. name -> 3
```

Mathematica doesn't recognise the "name" symbol and returns the following error:

"FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {0. -1. name} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {y$21486} = {0.}.

ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[y214862+2y21486-name,{y$21486,0}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

If you set Nest to apply zero times or replace it with a function that doesn't repeat the code works fine. It also works if you replace FindRoot with a simple assignment for symbol "OP". However, it doesn't work if you use Solve instead of FindRoot. Can anyone shine any light on this?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Then, where's the `FindRoot`?

Comment: you can not do find root on expression with symbolic symbol in it like this. Try `FindRoot[y^2 + 2 y - x == 0, {y, 0}]` and you'll see. `name` is like `x` here. ps. you changed the question, so will delete my answer below.

Comment: Apologies my mistake - I've updated it with the original code which includes FindRoot now.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1933647).

Comment: Restrict the argument: `del[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{y, dP, res, OP}, 
  res := y /. FindRoot[y^2 + 2 y - x, {y, 0}];
  OP := res;
  dP := OP + 1;
  Nest[(# + dP/#)/2 &, 1.5, 2]]`